# Parsing avro schema drops logicalType

Tags: c#, avro

I'm using Apache.Avro 1.10.1, and am trying to generate schemas at runtime.

It appears when parsing a schema, certain information is dropped. In the simple example below, field "something" has a logicalType set. When converting the parsed schema back to a string though, this information is missing.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string txt = @"
        {
            ""type"": ""record"",
            ""namespace"": ""test"",
            ""name"": ""Type1"",
            ""fields"": [
                {
                    ""name"": ""something"",
                    ""type"": ""int"",
                    ""logicalType"": ""date""
                }
            ]
        }
        ";

        var schema = Avro.Schema.Parse(txt);
        var str = schema.ToString();
        // str has the following value, i.e. is missing logicalType:
        // {"type":"record","name":"Type1","namespace":"test","fields":[{"name":"something","type":"int"}]}
    }
}
```

Has anyone run into this before?

I'm not entirely sure if it's a usage error on my end, or a bug in the library itself.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known bug that hasn't had any traction in years. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1556

Comment: Thanks Scott, that's good to know (and equally disheartening)! I'll probably move away from Avro again, that does not bode well for general health of its implementation(s)